# DataGridView's SelectionChange event firing twice on DataBinding even after removing event binding

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

This Code triggers selection change event twice. how can I prevent it ?
Currently i m using a flag or focused property to prevent this. But what is the actual way ?

I am using it on **winfoms**

**EDIT**

**My Mistake in writing Question, here is the correct code that i wanted to ask**

```
private void frmGuestInfo_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
this.dgvGuestInfo.SelectionChanged -= new System.EventHandler(this.dgvGuestInfo_SelectionChanged);
dgvGuestInfo.DataSource=dsFillControls.Tables["tblName"];
this.dgvGuestInfo.SelectionChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.dgvGuestInfo_SelectionChanged);
}

private void dgvGuestInfo_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//this function is raised twice, i was expecting that this will not be raised 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>The event will fire each time you set the `DataSource` property.</strike>

You should only set `DataSource` once.

You might be adding the same event handler twice.
Right-click on `dgvGuestInfo_SelectionChanged` and click Find All References.

Also, check the call stack in the event handler.

Comment: Why this happens, how could it be avoided. I even canceled event at the moment i am setting datasouce and rebinding the event after that. Then why it still raises event

Comment: Why are you setting `DataSource` twice?  Put a breakpoint in the handler, disable `Just My Code`, and look at the call stack.

Comment: Also, make sure you aren't adding the handler twice.  Right-click on `dgvGuestInfo_SelectionChanged` and click Find All References.

Answer (score 0):

I have your very same problem: sometimes deregistering from SelectionChanged works, sometimes not.

And I'm unregistering/reregistering in a try/finally construct:

```
            this.SelectionChanged -= ManageSelectionChanged;

            try
            {
                // code that could fire this.SelectionChanged
            }
            finally
            {                    
                this.SelectionChanged += ManageSelectionChanged;                 
            }
```

I've choosen to use a private flag too, but... I'm still curious.